# Resize course feature imge in moodle 2

Tags: php, moodle

I am using Moodle 2.8 and want to resize course feature image, because in home page many courses are rendered with large image size e.g. 2M or 3M. I want to use thumb version of the image instead of full image. Thanks in advance